# Javascript in HTML not calling correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple website using basic java script but I think i'm not able to call to the file correctly have tried multiple sources online but to no success. Can you have a look at my code and tell me what's wrong ?

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/js1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
The total number of square feet in your house is:<br>
<script src="js/js1.js">test()</script>square feet.
```

js:

```
function test() {
    var test = 15;
    document.write(test);
    return test;
}
```

Comment: function should include `( )` and should be `document.write`

Comment: I edited the above code however nothing appears on the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have put an `>` after `test()` for which there is an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

`<script src="js/js1.js">test()></script>square feet.`

```html
<head>
<script>
function test() {
    var test = 15;
    document.write(test);
    return test;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
The total number of square feet in your house is:<br>
<script>test()</script> square feet.
```

Comment: How do I call to the external javascript? I have multiple functions I want to try throughout the page, and want to avoid placing all the functions in the head tag.

Comment: Include your external javascript in the head tag as you have done.
Code sample was just for a demo.

Comment: Yeah using what I have still has no results on the page for some reason.

Comment: Yeah one syntax error that I found in the js. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
<script src="js/js1.js">test()></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script>test()</script>
```

Comment: Or the call to test should be in the js file below the function definition.

Comment: Is something wrong with the javascript? When changing the script nothing appears on the webpage.

Comment: @Devin as klvs said, put the first script element before the one with test() call

Comment: I've edited the above code to what I have now, however nothing is appearing on the webpage. Moving the script src out of the head and below the ran script at the end of the body changed nothing either.

Answer (score 0):

Base on @MoustafaS's answer, your js file can be fixed:

```
function test() {
    var test = 15;
    document.write(test);
    return test;
}
```

Then call it in HTML:

```
<script>test()</script>
```

---

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/234jo02m/)